# Parse nested JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, nested

I have stored data in sql server as Json format, which as give below. I would like to retrieve it as normal string value. I have tried JSON_VALUE but json may or may not have more than one child, so it should retrieve all the values.

**Input**

> TableA

```
   ID Education
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1  {"Education": {"Record":[{"SLSubject":"MICRO ECONOMICS","Score":"77","Grade":"A"}]}}
    2  {"Education": {"Record":[{"SLSubject":"Math","Score":"89","Grade":"A"},{"SLSubject":"eng","Score":"88","Grade":"B"},{"SLSubject":"tam","Score":"33","Grade":"C"}]}}
    3  {"Education":{"Record":[{"SLSubject":"subject 1","Score":"87","Grade":"A"},{"SLSubject":"subject 2","Score":"67","Grade":"B"},{"SLSubject":"subject 3","Score":"45","Grade":"C"},{"SLSubject":"subject 4","Score":"87","Grade":"D"}]}}
```

**Expected Output**

```
ID Education
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  MICRO ECONOMICS - 77 - A
2  Math - 88 - B \n end - 88 - B \n Tam - 33 - C
3  subject 1 - 87- A \n subject 2 - 67- B \n subject 3 - 45- C \n subject 1 - 87- D \n
```

**Query** (which is working for one child)

```
SELECT ID, JSON_VALUE(Education,'$.Education.Record[0].SLSubject')
FROM TableA
```

**Actual Result**

```
ID Education
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  MICRO ECONOMICS - 77 - A
2  Math - 88 - B
3  subject 1 - 87- A
```

**Sample JSON:**

```
{"Education":{"Record":[{"SLSubject":"subject 1","Score":"87","Grade":"A"},{"SLSubject":"subject 2","Score":"67","Grade":"B"},{"SLSubject":"subject 3","Score":"45","Grade":"C"},{"SLSubject":"subject 4","Score":"87","Grade":"D"}]}}
```

Comment: Why do you not want a normalised data set?

Comment: We will send report to the user for validation. To send that report we need to show education record of the candidate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `OPENJSON` and treat your data as a dataset, `JSON_VALUE` is for returning a scalar value. This'll likely be what you really want:

```
SELECT YT.ID,
       OJ.SLSubject,
       OJ.Score,
       OJ.Grade
FROM (VALUES(1,N'[{"SLSubject":"MICRO ECONOMICS","Score":"77","Grade":"A"}]'),
            (2,N'[{"SLSubject":"Math","Score":"89","Grade":"A"},{"SLSubject":"eng","Score":"88","Grade":"B"},{"SLSubject":"tam","Score":"33","Grade":"C"}]'),
            (3,N'[{"SLSubject":"subject 1","Score":"87","Grade":"A"},{"SLSubject":"subject 2","Score":"67","Grade":"B"},{"SLSubject":"subject 3","Score":"45","Grade":"C"},{"SLSubject":"subject 4","Score":"87","Grade":"D"}]'))YT(ID,Education) 
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(YT.Education) 
                 WITH (SLSubject varchar(20),
                       Score int,
                       Grade char(1)) OJ;
```

Seems the OP wants this?

```
SELECT YT.ID,
       STRING_AGG(CONCAT(OJ.SLSubject, ' - ', OJ.Score, ' - ', OJ.Grade),' \n ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OJ.SLSubject) AS Education
FROM (VALUES(1,N'[{"SLSubject":"MICRO ECONOMICS","Score":"77","Grade":"A"}]'),
            (2,N'[{"SLSubject":"Math","Score":"89","Grade":"A"},{"SLSubject":"eng","Score":"88","Grade":"B"},{"SLSubject":"tam","Score":"33","Grade":"C"}]'),
            (3,N'[{"SLSubject":"subject 1","Score":"87","Grade":"A"},{"SLSubject":"subject 2","Score":"67","Grade":"B"},{"SLSubject":"subject 3","Score":"45","Grade":"C"},{"SLSubject":"subject 4","Score":"87","Grade":"D"}]'))YT(ID,Education) 
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(YT.Education) 
                 WITH (SLSubject varchar(20),
                       Score int,
                       Grade char(1)) OJ
GROUP BY YT.ID;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d4edb99505be0fcee29eb6900b06d76d)

Comment: Thanks but i wanted in single column as Subject, Score and Grade as combined.

Comment: `Subject`, `Score`, and `Grade` *are* on a single row @VigneshKumarA . Do you mean "column"? A row is the horizontal part of the datagrid (in this case, will contain a single value for `ID`, `Subject`, `Score`, and `Grade`). A Column is the vertical part of the datagrid, so will contain **all** the values for a specific data piece (such as `Score`).

Comment: Use `CONCAT`: `CONCAT(OJ.SLSubject,'-',OJ.Score,'-',OJ.Grade)`@VigneshKumarA

Comment: But ID:2 will have more than one rows for education know

Comment: So you want to aggregate the columns **and** rows? Like that @VigneshKumarA?

Comment: Great, glad to have helped, @VigneshKumarA. Please do consider marking this as the solution if it solved the problem, so that future readers know it was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I am using sql server 2014, so both queries are not supporting

Comment: You bring that up now..? You'll need to use someo e else then, JSON support doesn't exist in SQL SERVER 2014.

Comment: @Larnu This approach (using `OPENJSON` and string aggregation with `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML PATH`) is also my first option in this case (of course for SQL Server 2016+). +1 from my side.